# ODT (LibreOffice) support on iOS

Tags: ios, file-format, word-processor, libreoffice

I recently started using [LibreOffice Writer](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/) instead of Microsoft Word because of the hassle of reinstalling and reactivating Word on a new computer, and it's not too bad. Writer is not a perfect substitute for Word, but I already use PDF when I need the document layout to be reproduced accurately, and LibreOffice is better at making PDFs than Microsoft Office.

But because LibreOffice displays a warning discouraging me from using the .docx format,  I've been using .odt for drafts. Recently I tried to check a few words in one of those drafts while I was away from my desktop, and I realised that I didn't have an iOS app for it.

I had a quick look into the horror that is the App Store and I couldn't see an easy, free solution, just a huge number of dodgy-looking apps with IAPs. So I waited until I was back at a desktop and then resolved to switched back to .docx, for which iOS has limited but adequate native support.

**Is there an iOS app that can read .odt files, and which:**

- Is relatively lightweight, so it can be downloaded and installed over a cellular connection?
- Doesn't require or constantly nag the user to sign up for a subscription service?
- Doesn't assume that the user wishes to store their documents in iCloud or some other cloud storage service?

(If not, is the situation on Android any better?)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions that try to offer the full LibreOffice experience on Android / iOS, but those are usually very big and a bit clunky to use.

As a lightweight solution on both iOS and Android I'd recommend to check out our app: https://opendocument.app/ - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app for ios named [OOReader](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ooreader/id480844649) that will read ODT files. Its free and is available from the app store.